# Is it possible to make an object similar to Date()?

Tags: javascript

I have a small code below

```
var a=new Date('12/13/2018');
console.log(a);
//this will output "Thu Dec 13 2018 10:41:29 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)"
```

I want to make a custom object or constructor function that will work in a similar way. Is it possible in javascript?

I tried making a simple constructor function but its not functioning like I want to.

```
function Mdate(b){
    return b;
}
Mdate.prototype={
    add:function(){

    }
}
var c=new Mdate('12/13/18');
console.log(c);
//output is "Mdate {}"
```

As not to confuse anyone I am not trying to make a Date Object Copy but I'm trying to make a Custom Native Object like String, Number, Array and etc...

I want to have the variable that the new Object was stored to to display the Objects value while still having access to the object's prototype chain

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Species

Comment: You can always subclass `Date` via classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Date and define your own `toString` method which is what will be printed in the console.

```
class MDate extends Date{
    constructor(){
        super(...arguments);
    }
    toString(){
        return 'something'
    }
}
console.log(new MDate);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z753x4kv/